# Ubuntu Server 20.04 and Postfix: configure SPF for a subdomain return error: spf=neutral and all emails marked as spam

Tags: server, dns, email, postfix

I'm trying to set up Postfix in Ubuntu Server 20.04 as an email sender (I don't need to receive emails) in my subdomain server.

I have the main domain that works with one server, and a subdomain that works with another server (with a different public IP). To better understand, this is the DNS setup:

```
- mydomain.com, (type) A, IP 185.xx.xxx.xxx
- subdom.mydomain.com, (type) A, IP 87.xx.xx.xxx (this is an home server)
```

I'm trying to configure the SPF on my DynamicDNS provider panel like this (DNS name are resolved by a DDNS provider):

```
- subdom.mydomain.com, (type) TXT, IP 87.xx.xx.xxx, v=spf1 a include:subdom.mydomain.com -all
```

I already configured SSL certificate for subdom.mydomain.com, but every email that I send will be received in the spam folder with error:

**"spf=neutral google.com: 87.xx.xx.xxx is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of myemail@subdom.mydomain.com"**

How can I fix my SPF to avoid that all email will be marked as spam?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add ip4:1.2.3.0/CIDR and ~all in spf record can solve issue. But this is not good because someone who has that ip range can send mail will be authenticated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I need to insert the public IP of my email server with CIDR at the end? 
Otherwise, I can add all the IP's that my provider could assign me, I remember that in total are 10 different IP's.

Thank you

Comment: if you are getting 10 IP then find out network IP, CIDR and modify in spf accordingly.

Comment: Yes you can add at end,  can add all the ip but spf accept 255 letters including space.

Comment: I checked and my internet service provider assign me more than 10 IP's, I stopped the counting at 50 :) I can't add all my IP's to the SPF. I think that I need to try to configuring my main domain "mydomain.com", but I can't do this because it's another server with another public IP... :(

Comment: Otherwise I should try to use Gmail as a relayhost... could be a good idea?

Comment: But, if I will use Gmail as a relayhost, it would be impossible for me to use the subdomain name in the email address, like "myemail@subdom.mydomain.com". Right?

Comment: @MarGraz you can use your primary domain as a relay server. I think primary domain on static public IP.

Comment: @MarGraz right!, You can not use your domain email if you will use Gmail.